# Use 1:n DeleteActions

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, cascading-deletes

How is it possible to use DeleteActions for 1:n table-relations?

Example:

```
Table A ("id")
('foo')
,('bar')
,('blup')

Table B: ("id", "tableAId1", "tableAId2")
(1, 'foo', 'blup')
,(2, 'bar', 'foo')
```

I have two relations on tableB:

```
TableB:tableAId1 -> TableA:id
TableB:tableAId2 -> TableA:id
```

Both datasets in table B should be deleted, if 'foo' from table A is deleted.

I tried one delete-Action on table A, refering to table B with cascade-option, resulting in **only dataset 1** in table B was deleted.

I tried two identical delete-Action on table A, refering to table B with cascade-option, resulting in table lock on database.

I know about overwriting `delete()` method on table A, but this isn't safe if using `tableA.doDelete()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AX 2009 and previous a delete action on a table only follows one of the relations (the first alphabetically sorted). A table should only be applied as a delete action once.

Your best choice then is to do your own cascade delete using `delete_from` in the `delete` method of your master table. If you do a `doDelete`, it will not delete the child records. Then just don't use the `doDelete` method!

In AX 2012 you explicitly specify which relation to follow on a delete action. You can apply the same table more than once, provided you specify different relations.

This is a nice feature, but is one of the reasons that table relations on the extended data types had to die.

Comment: The explicit relation definition in 2012 is known. I hoped for a "workaround" to avoid possible orphaned records due to a doDelete() - and sure, me myself can use a delete(), but I can't control other users! Thanks anyway for the answer - I'll mark it as the correct one, thus I already thought your described way would be the most rightful one.

Comment: Hopefully users cannot do `doDelete`, programmers might, but then it would be to avoid the cascade.